# how to get parent or calling url of http request in c#?

Tags: c#, http

I created http post request, user can call this request from their website(client) and i receive that request on server side.
now i want find the parent host of that request.

> I tried using request.Urlreferrer, but that is coming null.

is there is any other method to find out calling host of httprequest.

Comment: try Request.RequestUri.Host

Comment: Request.RequestUri.Host will give the host of the httprequest, but i want the host of the parent url. like if website A is calling my httprequest the i want the host of website A.

Comment: Is your method called using ajax? If so, check the `Origin` header of the incoming request.

Answer (score 0):

`Request.ServerVariables("remote_addr")` and `Request.ServerVariables("remote_host")` both return the IP address of the client.

If you need the name:

```
string[] computers     System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName.Split(new Char[] { '.' });
 String ecn = System.Environment.MachineName;
 String  name = computer_name[0].ToString();
```

For client URI:

```
HttpRequest.UserHostAddress
```

Comment: yes this will provide the IP but i am not able to get the host URl